# str.title() and encoding on mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, encoding

Let's say I have 3 folders named "Grégory MM", "Loïc RR" and "Danièle RR" (spaces and accented letters).

Then I use the following code to get all the names with only the first letter capitalized:

```
import glob
names = [ x.title() for x in glob.glob('*') ]
```

If the folders were created with `mkdir` from a Terminal I have the expected result:

```
>>> names
['Loïc Rr', 'Danièle Rr', 'Grégory Mm']
```

If the folders were created from the Finder, I get:

```
>>> names
['LoïC Rr', 'DanièLe Rr', 'GréGory Mm']
```

The first letter after each accented letter is capitalized. Is that a known behavior? How can I avoid it?

Python version 3.7.0
System: macOS Mojave 10.14.1
and `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` returns 'utf-8'

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a matter of whether the accented letters use combining accent characters or single accented code points. I don't know what file names you actually have on your system, but putting the names in NFC form (with single accented code points):

```
>>> x = 'Loïc Rr'
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFC', x).title()
'Loïc Rr'
```

we get no capital after the accent, while in NFD form (with combining accent characters):

```
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFD', x).title()
'Loi\u0308C Rr'
```

we get the capital.

It looks like `title()` thinks the combining character marks a word boundary. NFC normalization can help somewhat, but not for weird accent combinations for which a dedicated code point doesn't exist. For more robust handling, you may want to look for a more powerful Unicode handling library than Python's built-in string methods.

Answer (score 1):

We actually have two different strings:

```
In [1]: 'Loïc Rr'.encode()
Out[1]: b'Lo\xc3\xafc Rr'

In [2]: 'Loïc Rr'.encode()
Out[2]: b'Loi\xcc\x88c Rr'
```

`\xc3\xaf` is `ï` and `\xcc\x88` is `̈`,

`\xcc\x88` is recognized as punctuation, so that's the reason why `title()` capitalizes your letter.

You can normalize your string with [`unicodedata.normalize()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#module-unicodedata):

```
In [1]: import unicodedata

In [2]: 'Loïc Rr' == 'Loïc Rr'
Out[2]: False

In [3]: unicodedata.normalize('NFC','Loïc Rr') == unicodedata.normalize('NFC','Loïc Rr')
Out[3]: True

In [4]: unicodedata.normalize('NFD','Loïc Rr') == unicodedata.normalize('NFD','Loïc Rr')
Out[4]: True

In [5]: unicodedata.normalize('NFD','Loïc Rr').title() == unicodedata.normalize('NFD','Loïc Rr').title()
Out[5]: True

In [6]: unicodedata.normalize('NFD','Loïc Rr').title() == unicodedata.normalize('NFD','Loïc Rr').title()
Out[6]: True
```

Comment: `unicodedata.normalize` helps somewhat, but it won't do anything for accent combinations that don't have a dedicated code point.